# Choosing a color based on exam score

Tags: php

How can I simplify this code?

```
<?php
class smth {
    protected static $MARK_UNDEFINED = 'Undefined';
    protected static $MARK_F  = 'ECTS-F';
    protected static $MARK_FX = 'ECTS-FX';
    protected static $MARK_E  = 'ECTS-E';
    protected static $MARK_D  = 'ECTS-D';
    protected static $MARK_C  = 'ECTS-C';
    protected static $MARK_B  = 'ECTS-B';
    protected static $MARK_A  = 'ECTS-A';

    protected function getECTSMark($rate, $current, $examRate)
    {
        $color = self::$MARK_UNDEFINED;
        if ($current > 0) {
            $percent = $rate / $current;
            if ($examRate !== NULL AND $examRate < 22)
                $color = self::$MARK_FX;
            elseif ($percent < 0.31)
                $color = self::$MARK_F;
            elseif ($percent < 0.60)
                $color = self::$MARK_FX;
            elseif ($percent < 0.65)
                $color = self::$MARK_E;
            elseif ($percent < 0.71)
                $color = self::$MARK_D;
            elseif ($percent < 0.85)
                $color = self::$MARK_C;
            elseif ($percent < 0.95)
                $color = self::$MARK_B;
            else
                $color = self::$MARK_A;
        }
        return $color;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much how you do that.  I'm pretty sure that there are some other languages that directly support ranged items in "case" expressions, and there's a GCC extension that allows it for GCC languages.. one slightly hacky way that you can achieve that, in PHP, because PHP actually evaluates expressions in cases, unlike many other languages, is:

    switch(true) {
        case ($percent < 0.31): $color = self::$MARK_F; break;
        ....
    }

.. oh, hey formatting doesn't work in comments.

Comment: You could also try to use an associative array instead and use a for loop - but I'm not sure if this is better performance wise. I'm talking about an array like array('ECTS-F' => 0.31, 'ECTS-FX' => 0.6 ... ) and keep your exception for that examRate lower than 22.

Comment: It would be simpler (to understand) if your code had some useful comments with it. It's not very complicated code, but still, what do $rate, $current, $examRate, and $color exactly represent? Why $color when it clearly isn't a color? Why $percent, when it isn't a percentage? What is $MARK_FX? Is this all the code, or is it just a part of a bigger whole? Such insights are needed to, perhaps, find a completely different way of solving what you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Have to agree with @KIKO, we can clearly tell what your code is doing, but we do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: I do not advocate this to be used, it is definitely wrong, untested, horrible and confusing.**

But it should give you a start in using the associative array method that Alexander Kludt noted in his comment.

```
<?php
class Smth 
{
    protected $marks = array(
        'Undefined' => 0, 'ECTS-F' => 0.31, 'ECTS-FX' => 0.60, 'ECTS-E' => 0.65, 
        'ECTS-D' 0.71, 'ECTS-C' => 0.85, 'ECTS-B' => 0.95, 'ECTS-A'
    );

    public function getEctsMark($rate, $current, $examRate) 
    {
        $color = reset($this->marks);
        $percent = $rate / $current;

        if($current > 0 && $examRate < 22) {
            return "ECTS-FX";
        }

        /**
         * This is where the explanation is required. This *should* *maybe*
         * compare the percent to the current start band and the next band. So 
         * say for example the percent is 0.78(78%) this would foreach through 
         * the  marks array and eventually return true on >= $percentStart(0.71)
         * and <= the next band start up which is 0.85.
         */
        $i = 0;
        foreach($this->marks as $key => $percentStart) {
            if($percent >= $percentStart && $percentStart <= $this->marks[$i+1]) {
                $color = $key;
                break;
            }           
            $i++;
        }

        return $color;
    }
}
```

If you are wanting feedback on your original code, I made a few changes which might satisfy your criteria of simplification over at this [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/QuveB).